# Javascript Intellisense in IDE

Tags: javascript, eclipse, intellij-idea, ide, webstorm

How does Intellisense work in IDEs for JavaScript such as Webstorm or Eclipse?

Where do the suggestions come from?

Can we write the code to make the suggestions more accurate?

[image: Sample image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/07/how-webstorm-works-completion-for-javascript-libraries/ for some hints on improving JavaScript code completion in WebStorm. In general: suggestions are taken from index that is built for all .js and d.ts files available in the project/set up as libraries. To make the completion better, you can try using JSDoc annotations/typescript definition stubs

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I ment. Do you think it works for other IDEs as well?

Comment: In other JetBrains IDEs - yes. Not sure about javascript support in Eclipse

Comment: I found this library http://ternjs.net/doc/demo/#simple which works for other IDEs as well

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse you can write plug-ins which use the [org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.ui.javaCompletionProposalComputer](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.jsdt.doc%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_wst_jsdt_ui_javaCompletionProposalComputer.html) extension point to contribute additional Content Assist proposals.

Eclipse gives you access to an [Abstract Syntax Tree](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.wst.jsdt.doc%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fwst%2Fjsdt%2Fcore%2Fdom%2FAST.html) of the code to help with analyzing the source.

Comment: The AST tells you about functions, variables and the like in the source. You then have to use that information to work out what is possible at the current location. This is a **very** complex area.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer, I'm the author of [tern.java](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/)

I suggest you that you try tern.java by starting to read [Getting Started](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Getting-Started)

Comment: Yes, I mentioned your product in my comment to Lena. Looks very interesting